# How can I separate string and code

Tags: php, string, blogs, highlight

I'm taking some data from database for my blog. In the article I may have a string with an explanation or something else and I have some codes between `<code></code>` tags.

I tried to highlight that code with:

```
<?
echo highlight_string($data["article"]);
?>
```

and the whole article looks like PHP code but I could not figure out how I can highlight the codes which is in `<code></code>`. I want to colorize just the codes in code tags.

**Thank you all guys I solve it myself :). Solution is like bottom.**

```
echo preg_replace('~\<code\>(.*?)\<\/code\>~ise', "highlight_string(stripslashes(stripslashes('\\1')),true);", $data["article"]);
```

[This is the solution excatly what I want.](http://s11.postimg.org/tubrcfi03/Untitled_2.gif)

Comment: Please edit question and ask properly what you exactly want?

Comment: $data holds formated HTML tags?

Comment: no it's article and some php codes in code tags.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a [**syntax highlighter**](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting code is a quite common problem on the web, and as it is a presentation issue, it is usually more efficient to do the process directly on the client side, rather than in PHP.

There are many Javascript libraries for this, let me name a few:

http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/

https://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/

http://craig.is/making/rainbows

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just forget tell  ***php*** is the language selected:

```
<?php
echo highlight($data["article"]);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell for certain, but based on the question and several comments, it sounds like your function `highlight()` will "highlight" whatever you pass it as an argument. (You should probably style this with css instead. See far below.)

You say that calling it like this, `highlight($data["article"]);` is highlighting the whole article. That kind of makes sense, if `highlight()`'s job is to highlight whatever you pass it. You're passing the whole article.

To make it highlight operate only on code, I'd expect you to pass *only* the code to it. So in the middle of your article, wherever you have a snippet of code, pass *that* to the `highlight()` function.  Instead of this,

```
<p>This is part of a paragraph inside your article, 
and it has <code>a little bit of code</code> inside it.</p>
```

do something like this.

```
<p>This is part of a paragraph inside your article, 
and it has <?php echo highlight('<code>a little bit of code</code>'); ?> inside it.</p>
```

Of course, it *could* be that `highlight()` is supposed to do a global search-and-replace on `<code>` tags, and embed the highlighting style *in* the code tags. There's no way for us to tell by just reading the original question.

**Consider styling all your `<code></code>` with css instead.**  A section like this between the `<head>` and `</head>` is all you really need to highlight all the code elements.

```
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    code {background-color:yellow;}
  </style>
</head>
```

The important part is between the "style" tags. This illustrates how to do it with an *internal* stylesheet. Personally, I prefer *external* stylesheets, but that means making an additional file, and that seems to be too much for this question.

Comment: Is there any function we can separete <code> tags I try this
$code=split("<code>",$data["article"];
highlight_string($code[1]);

Comment: No intrinsic function, but you can use an HTML parser. Seriously, though, that's like kicking dead whales down the beach. You *really* should style this with CSS. And you should fix the problem at the root cause.

Comment: Actually, you *could* use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), an intrinsic function, to replace the `<code>` tag with a tag that has the styling inline, but I don't think that's a good solution here.